# Алгоритм распознавания состояний глаз - открыты/закрыты

Tags: распознавание

Добрый день.
Требуется реализовать алгоритм, позволяющий определять, в каком состоянии находятся его глаза, если можно так выразиться. Нужно определять состояния Открыты, Закрыты, можно еще Закрыты на хх%.
Буду признателен за подсказки, где можно про это почитать.

**UPD**
Прошу только навести, где есть информация о распознавании глаз.

Comment: Просто догадка -- надо искать блик (видимо смотреть его контрастность). У открытых глаз он должен быть более выраженным. / (не очень понимаю, зачем минусовать то, что непонятно).

Comment: @avp, хотелось бы, что бы алгоритм работал и с широкими зрачками  (в темное время суток зрачки расширяются, другой вопрос, как  снимать такое лицо). / ну, я же новичек, можно сразу пинать, видимо кто-то считает задачу тривиальной или уже разжеванной

Comment: Я же говорю, это только догадка. На самом деле я никогда таким распознаванием не занимался. А разве с широкими зрачками этот же алгоритм не сработает? Ведь вроде бы тоже получаем большую контрастную область... (а задача, безусловно не тривиальна. Скорее тут экспериментировать надо не бояться, чем искать готовые гуглодоступные решения).

Comment: @avp, да, конечно, спасибо, можно попробовать, осталось решить задачу, как найти область на изображении лица, где находятся глаза.

Comment: @metalurgus, вопрос отредактировал.

Comment: Поискать можно по запросу OpenCV и Computer Vision возможно там что-то будет подобное, но скорее всего допиливать прийдется однозначно.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, к сожалению вообще никакой информации найти не удается по данной теме, поэтому спрашиваю. Я же прошу указать на конкретный источник, название книги например. Понимаю, что тема обширная, поэтому дать полный ответ тут не возможно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, скажу прямо. И на ХК-то было мало вопросов над которыми стоило бы подумать. А здесь с таким подходом к закрытию всего неоднозначного подобных тем просто не будет. Возможно цель "накопления знаний" этим и будет достигнута, только вот каков будет уровень тех программистов, кому нужны такие знания?

Comment: @avp Сообщество и ранее старалось закрывать подобные вопросы. Наша главная задача - это сбор полезной информации, если вы считаете вопрос интересным, я несомненно голосую за повторное открытие. Все же, вопросы опросники не являются для нас тематическими, так как зачастую порождают "религиозные войны".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, конкретно этот может быть интересным. Реально подобный софт есть в некоторых фотокамерах, про сами алгоритмы я не знаю. Если кто-то, обладающий такими знаниями увидит вопрос (м.б. случайно наткнется, т.к. подозреваю, что при нормальном развитии событий быть ему неотвеченным) и поделится своими знаниями IMHO все выиграют. / А чего Вы так боитесь holywars (мусор, конечно)? Ну, повисит пара тем в топе недельку (за это время все равно всем надоест), ничего же (кроме траффика) от этого не изменится.

Comment: @avp Если Вы не возражаете, то я бы подготовил ответ на ваш вопрос и затем опубликовал его на Мете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, конечно, не возражаю.

Comment: Да, я тоже видел подобное в одном софте - наблюдает за работающим за компьютером в реальном времени. Программа делает напоминания, что чаще надо моргать, отдыхать и т.д. - для сохранения зрения. Но вот никакую литературу найти не получается. Практическая потребность в данной задаче есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача очень нетривиальна и, предваряя поиск решения, требует конкретизации условий, в которых необходимо производить детекцию моргания или просто текущего состояния глаз в кадре: открыты или закрыты.

Возьмём, к примеру, стандартный случай.

Если на исходном изображении лицо не заполняет всю видимую область, то таковую необходимо локализовать. Для решения этой задачи существует не так уж и много решений, но то, что имеется в подавляющем количестве случаев более чем удобоваримо. Речь прежде всего о каскаде Хаара. Во многих фреймворках, так или иначе касающихся тематики компьютерного зрения, имеется реализация данного инструмента, позволяющая с относительно высокой точностью локализовать местоположение лица в кадре.

После нахождения региона, содержащего лицо, уже в нём необходимо локализовать местоположение обоих глаз. Как правило, начав с каскада Хаара в случае с лицом, не останавливаются в использовании этого же инструмента и для глаз. Просто берут соответствующий файл классификатора, заранее обученный на поиск желаемого типа объекта. К слову сказать, оба типа классификаторов (для лиц, глаз, да и других объектов) имеются во многим известном фреймворке OpenCV, ориентированном как раз на решение задач, навроде той, что встала перед автором вопроса.

Не стану останавливаться на задаче, как реализовать детекторы лиц и глаз посредством [каскада Хаара (метод Виолы-Джонса)](http://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/228195/) в том же OpenCV, так как об этом расписано в сети, наверное, вдоль и поперёк, да и вопрос конкретно не затрагивает эту область.

Предположим, что после применения алгоритмов детекции мы получили следующие изображения, отражающие два состояния глаз: открыты и закрыты.

[image: примеры входных изображений]

Изображения мною взяты исключительно для примера, но в реальности, если съёмка ведётся с обычной вебкамеры, области глаз получаются значительно меньше. Это просто в следствие того, что специально подносить собственную физиономию близко к объективу редко у кого возникает желание. Но именно в следствие этого (условий съёмки, упоминаемых мною в самом начале) как правило и начинаются расхождения в подходах к определению местоположения зрачка.

Методов по детекции зрачка разработано довольно много. От самых простых, до комплексных. Очень многие подробно расписаны (к сожалению в подавляющем большинстве случаев на английском). А для некоторых имеется и вполне свободный доступ к исходникам. На том же [гитхабе](https://github.com) можно обнаружить довольно много различных решений. Например [такое](https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike) или [такое](https://github.com/laoyang/ASEF). Последнее, кстати, не требует локализации области глаз, только лишь лица.

Вообще, детекция зрачка кажется очевидным путём для решения поставленной задачи: зрачок есть - глаз открыт, нет зрачка - глаз закрыт. Но у многих методов, идущих этим путём, имеется проблема с детекцией в том случае, если глаз полуприкрыт или закрыт вовсе. В этом случае происходят ложные срабатывания алгоритмов и те выдают местоположение зрачка аккурат на ресницах, "лежащих" на соединении верхнего и нижнего века. То есть, искомое состояние о закрытии глаза способны выдавать далеко не все методы.

Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать машинное обучение или даже предварительно сделать образцы открытого и закрытого глаз, а затем сравнивать с этими шаблонами новые кадры. Но можно пойти и от обратного, например, применив самый простой детектор кожи. Очевидно, что если глаз закрыт, цветом кожи будет покрыто практически всё изображение глаза, а если открыт, то далеко не всё.

```
int main() {
    // Загрузить изображения открытого и закрытого глаз из файлов.
    cv::Mat eye_opened_mat = cv::imread("eye-opened.jpg");
    cv::Mat eye_closed_mat = cv::imread("eye-closed.jpg");

    // Показать, что загрузили в отдельных окошках.    
    cv::imshow("eye-opened", eye_opened_mat);
    cv::imshow("eye-closed", eye_closed_mat);

    // Сконвертировать цветовое пространство изображений в YCbCr.  
    cv::Mat opened_mat, closed_mat;
    cv::cvtColor(eye_opened_mat, opened_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
    cv::cvtColor(eye_closed_mat, closed_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);

    // Изъять из картинок указанные диапазоны значений пикселей
    // для каждого из цветовых каналов YCbCr.
    cv::inRange(opened_mat, cv::Scalar(0,133,77), cv::Scalar(255,173,127), opened_mat);
    cv::inRange(closed_mat, cv::Scalar(0,133,77), cv::Scalar(255,173,127), closed_mat);

    // Показать результат в отдельных окошках.    
    cv::imshow("grd-opened", opened_mat);
    cv::imshow("grd-closed", closed_mat);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код использует OpenCV. Результат будет следующий:

[image: пример работы детектора кожи]

Разница между закрытым и открытым глазами очевидна и не составит никакого труда алгоритму выдать правильный ответ о состоянии глаза. Преимуществом данного подхода является скорость. Работает он очень быстро. Недостаток: чувствительность к перепадам освещённости, ну и конечно к неграм (без обид), для цвета кожи которых придётся подбирать иные коэффициэнты.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - натренировать детектор Viola-Jones. В матлабе уже есть [детектор глаз](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector-class.html). Можно натренировать детектор отркытых глаз, и детектор закрытых глаз с помощью функции [trainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html).

Другой вариант - использовать детектор глаз, а потом решать открыты они или закрыты с помощью [HOG-SVM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html).